# forgot password with django and graphql?

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm using django as the backed with graphql,im trying to implement forgot password,and change password,im using django-graphql-jwt for login ,everything's is works,but i  didn't see any documentation about the forgot password with graphql.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: jwt login with query and mutations are working properly.@thatrockbottomprogrammer

Comment: Generate tokens using which password can be changed. Store it in temporary storage like Redis with user id and reverse lookup the record to change the password

Comment: i know how to it with rest but in graphql i have no idea how to generate the forgot password link.

Comment: @AJAIAU, have you figured out something?

Comment: @AJAIAU see if my answer helps, feel free to ask me questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-graphql-auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

It has built-in mutations for [send password reset email](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#sendpasswordresetemail) and [password reset](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#passwordreset).

## Request the password reset email

```sh
mutation {
  sendPasswordResetEmail(
    email: "skywalker@email.com"
  ) {
    success,
    errors
  }
}
```

## User receives email with link

The link contain a token that you use on the client side to send the mutation:

```sh
mutation {
  passwordReset(
    token: "1eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNreXdhbGtlciIsImFjdGlvbiI6InBhc3N3b3JkX3Jlc2V0In0:1itExL:op0roJi-ZbO9cszNEQMs5mX3c6s",
    newPassword1: "supersecretpassword",
    newPassword2: "supersecretpassword"
  ) {
    success,
    errors
  }
}
```

disclaimer: I'm the author

Comment: tried using it, but I can't seem to be able to send email